# is it possible to run and write code for Jmeter 3.3 with intellij? (java 8)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, intellij-plugin

is there a way too run/debug/wrote code for Jmeter using IntelliJ.
I just found that it is possible for java 6
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7013-jmeter-plugin

but I am using Jmeter 3.3.
Is their a way to do it? is there any special instructions?
regards

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use the same plugin for configuring and running JMeter tests directly from IntelliJ Idea, normally Java is backward-compatible so it should not be a problem to use Java 8 with this JMeter Idea Plugin.

Just install the plugin, provide path to your JMeter in its settings and you should be good to go

[image: JMeter Idea Plugin]

If you need to debug your own custom samplers or existing JMeter code - you can do it without any plugins, just treat JMeter as "normal" Java application (which is the case), so if you launch JMeter as:

```
java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 -jar ApacheJMeter.jar
```

You will be able to connect Idea by creating a new "Remote" configuration

[image: JMeter Remote Debugging]

See [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) guide for more information